# Convert ios app to android using phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have made a sample application in ios using phonegap framework.  I have used plugins for navigation bar and tab bar. Now I want to deploy my app to android. so what should I do now? Whether I should make it for android also using phonegap framework with eclipse or  is there any other way to do it? can I make the build directly for android using phone gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in android,set the weblink below the `setcontentview`  in mainactivity in android

Comment: So it means that I have to use phonegap with eclipse to make it for android.right?

Comment: this link guide you:  [android link1]  (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)   and use this too...                    [android link2:](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)

Comment: Would it be also possible to use PhoneGap to make convert from iOS to Android?